# GWT annotated timeline chart - more series in range selector

Tags: gwt, charts, timeline

Is there any way to add more series of data to be shown in range selector below actual chart. Now it is only one although i have two series of data in chart.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, currently not. I am dealing with the same issue. The range selector is always showing the first graph added to the chart.